Typescript npm run tsc errors when deploying firebase functions
When I run npm run build or npm run deploy I got the following errors:
...

../../node_modules/discord.js/typings/index.d.ts:1211:9 - error TS1005: ')' expected.

1211     name: string,
             ~

../../node_modules/discord.js/typings/index.d.ts:1211:11 - error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.

1211     name: string,
               ~~~~~~

../../node_modules/discord.js/typings/index.d.ts:1212:13 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

1212     required: true,
                 ~

../../node_modules/discord.js/typings/index.d.ts:1213:18 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

1213     channelTypes?: readonly Type[],
                      ~
...

The tsconfig is:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es2016",
    /* Modules */
    "module": "CommonJS",
    // "rootDir": "./",                                  /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@models/*": ["models/*"],
      "@controllers/*": ["controllers/*"],
      "@middlewares/*": ["middlewares/*"]
    }
  }
}

package.json:
{
  "name": "@packages/functions",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^12.1.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^5.0.0",
    "shuffle-seed": "^1.1.6",
    "@formkit/tempo": "^0.1.1",
    "@global/types": "1.0.0",
    "@global/utils": "1.0.0",
    "discord.js": "^14.14.1",
    "zod": "^3.22.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "@types/shuffle-seed": "^1.1.3"
  }
}

Run npm run build or npm run deploy and I get the error
